# How can I manually show "Canvas.Top" property in DevExpress PropertyGridControl?

Tags: c#, canvas, properties, devexpress

I have some elements in my Canvas and I show their properties in a PropertyGridControl when any of them is selected.

When I set ShowProperties="All", all properties are shown and Canvas.Top & Canvas.Left are there but when I manually show properties via ShowProperties="WithPropertyDefinitions" those wont show. How can I make them appear?

```xml
<dxprg:PropertyDefinition Path="Canvas.Top" />
<dxprg:PropertyDefinition Path="Canvas.Left" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Apparently the solution is bracketing the attached properties.

```xml
<dxprg:PropertyDefinition Path="(Canvas.Top)" />
<dxprg:PropertyDefinition Path="(Canvas.Left)" />
```